# Automate the process of flagging non constructive comments from User Supplied data

Tags: app, comments, flags

#### Warning

> While entering a comment ID, you should be careful because some comments may be removed with a single flag (if it already have some flags).

> Some comments may still constructive even if it contains Thank you or welcome. Don't flag such comments.

> Remember : The flags are raised from your account. Incorrect flags may give you a flag ban.

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

Home page

[image: home page]

Add Flag page

[image: flagging page]

### About

It's a Web Application, built using Angular and hosted on Firebase. I created it to automate the process of flagging non-constructive comments like "Thank you", "Welcome", etc.

We don't use comment heuristics. We use data from [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com). So you have to bring the data (comma-separated comment ids).

Comments are an essential part of some answers and sometimes, we have to look into the comment section too to understand the answer better. Seeing lots of "Thank you", "Welcome", "Please accept this answer", etc. is quite boring. That's why I created this app.

#### How to use?

1. Get the comment ids from https://data.stackexchange.com.
2. Visit [Auto Flagger](https://autoflagger.os.sagarvd.me/home)
3. Log in with Stack Exchange (if you haven't already).
4. Click on "Start flagging".
5. Paste comma-separated comment ids in the textarea and click "Start Flagging"

#### License

There's no License. You can use it as you wish.

#### Platform

Web

### Contact

Sagar V: https://sagarvd.me
Email: support@sagarvd.me

### Code

Framework used: Angular

The code needs some final touches before open-sourcing it.

Comment: The site is down.